# How to add math in PHP echo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math

I have a website that everything is working well except **lowest price**. I mean all prices will be changed based on selected currency but not lowest price.

Lowest Price is showing correctly just based on US dollar not other currencies, I mean If we will change currency to Euro, still lowest price is showing on US dollar which is default currency.

In my Sql Database I have a table **pt_currencie** and Column **rate**

and on my room page, lowest price is showing with following PHP code:

```
<?php echo $lowestPrice; ?>
```

and in the controller, the code is:

```
$this->data['lowestPrice'] = $this->hotels_lib->bestPrice($this->data['hotel']->id);
```

and here is setting for userdata and change currency

```
      function changeCurrency($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $rs = $this->db->get('pt_currencies')->result();
        $this->session->set_userdata('currencycode', $rs[0]->code);
        $this->session->set_userdata('currencysymbol', $rs[0]->symbol);
        $this->session->set_userdata('currencyname', $rs[0]->name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('currencyrate', $rs[0]->rate);
  }
```

}

How can I show $lowestPrice based on selected currency (rate) ?
what formula should I add into above code that lowest price show based on selected currency?

Comment: Do you have the conversion rates somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have but there's nothing inside related to lowest price that's why

Comment: Ok. So what do you want us to do?

Comment: Give me a code that it will convert lowest rate which is default to other currencies. I updated my question, you can see what's the function to change currency

Comment: How are you doing the conversion for other prices? Why can't you do it the same way for `#lowestPrice`?

Comment: The problem is about database, there's no column for lowestprice, I need a math code to solve it inside PHP file and also the page i'm gonna show it it's header section and there's no connection to db , That's why I need a PHP to calculate it inside of file

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I'm understanding your question correctly, you will have to take the currency rates out of the db into a php array and then determine the lowest price using php with something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT rate FROM pt_currencie";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

$rate_arr = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
$currLowestPrice = $lowestPrice;
foreach ($rate_arr as $rate) {
    $tmpLowestPrice = $lowestPrice * $rate;
    if($currlowestPrice > $tmpLowestPrice)
        $currLowestPrice = $tmpLowestPrice;
}
```

So this should atleast give you the lowest price in $currLowestPrice for adjusted to currency rates by the end of the for loop (the code above will probably have to be adjusted a bit for your program)